# Makefile generation tool for Android NDK prebuilt libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I'm doing a little bit of work with the Android NDK, and I'm spending a lot of time hand-editing the makefile for my prebuilt library every time I add or remove a source file. It seems like it should be possible to automate this. Are there any good tools for the job?

I'm a seasoned web/mobile developer but I'm brand new to building from the command line so it's entirely possible I'm overlooking an incredibly obvious right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard **/*.cpp)
```

(Assuming .cpp files is all your source.)